# Cannot change the dtype using tf.cast, when value passed is dataset.take(1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, casting, dtype

I want to change the dtype of one element of my dataset. (element shape = (32,28,28)--> this is one batch of 28 by 28 images in mnist dataset)

So i ran the following command: `tf.cast(dataset.take(1),tf.float32)`.

the type of my dataset is `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.PrefetchDataset`

It threw an error: `: Attempt to convert a value (<TakeDataset shapes: (32, 28, 28), types: tf.uint8>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.TakeDataset'>) to a Tensor.`

So i took one element from the dataset using the code:

```
    for batch_data in dataset:
        one_element = dataset
        break
```

and then I ran `tf.cast(one_element,tf.float32)` and it works.

May I know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tf.data.Dataset.take() returns Dataset not tensor (even when you call take(1)): https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset